Shell: How to print all files in a folder with cat with files separator
If I do cat * in a directory, then I cannot easily see when I switch from one file to the next. I would like to have a visual indication that the files are not the same. I tried options -n and -b but the same counter applies to all files. Is there any way to avoid a for loop to do this. I found the solution grep -r '' my_directory. Is there any other possibility ?

Use less command instead of cat, so you can scroll back and forth and also move from file to file. Read the manual for details.

If you have GNU sed, you can append some line to the end of every file, for instance:
sed -s '$a--- END OF FILE ---' -- *


The -s or --separate flag is to "consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream."

You can also insert a line before the first line:
sed -s -e '1i--- FILE BEGIN ---' -e '$a---  FILE END  ---\n' -- *

Additionally, you can add the file name before the first line using the F command.
sed -s -e 1F -e '1i--- FILE BEGIN ---' -e '$a---  FILE END  ---\n' -- *

